# Trouble with Spawning and Arrays in Unity3D

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, instantiation

I have an inventory window on a 2D game I'm creating in Unity (4.6) with individual slots that are populated with unique objects at the start of my game. Users can drag the objects from the slots onto a play area where they can arrange the object. Users can also trash an object (which would move it back to the inventory).

I've created an array to count the objects I have in my Layout Grid but from there I'm stuck on a few things:

1: How can I respawn a new copy of the object in the same slot that the previous object was dragged from and also set a max so users can only drag a specific number of the same objects out ?

2: How do I store/access an objects index in the Grid Layout Group so that when the objects get placed back in the inventory they go back to the same spot they were originally pulled from?

This is all I've got so far

```
public GameObject[] animalParts;

void Start () {
    // Get all of my animal parts indexed
    animalParts = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("AnimalPart");

    for(int i = 0; i < animalParts.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Animal part " + i + " is named " + animalParts[i].name);
    }
}
```

How do I now assign the index number to a variable in each animalPart so it can be recalled later when the object gets dragged back into inventory after it's been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a Data Structure for this. Like:

```
public struct AnimalPartObject
{
    public GameObject GO;
    public int Index;
    public int MaxItemsToSpawn;
}
```

And then you need to create a `List<AnimalPartObject> listOfParts;` in your Script to manage your objects which are spawned in the game. And attach a script to each Part Element to set its `AnimalPartObject` information.

I hope this solves your problem. Thumb up if it served the purpose. Thanks